# Renting EVs on the Canaries

Tags: car-rentals, canary-islands, tenerife, gran-canaria, electric-vehicle

As Bali seems to be a bit complicated at the moment regarding entry requirements and quarantining, I've been looking for alternatives. I've come across the Canary Islands and really like the idea of going there. Now, I would like to rent a car as I read that exploring the islands is much easier that way. I am not sure yet, which island exactly I will choose, Tenerife and Gran Canaria caught my attention for now.

I was wondering if any of you here has experience with renting an EV on the Canaries? I have never driven an electric car but I really like the idea of it. And I've been meaning to try one for ages anyway.
A quick Google Search showed [TopCar](https://top-car-hire.com/en) as one possible car rental agency. Does anyone here have experience with renting a car with them? The reviews look good but I always prefer to hear from a "real" person.

I am also open to any recommendations or other information you might have.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that CICAR offer electric car https://www.cicar.com/EN/view/coches-alquiler-electricos_EN. I don’t have experience with electric car rent but 4 years ago I use their rental car services. I was very satisfied and generally, they have good reviews

Comment: I'm from Tenerife and I have several rental companies. Rental Cars is not as cheap as the others but it is by far one with the most smooth and quickesr process.I have never tried TopCar

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into the companies that you and the comment below mentioned!

Comment: I was satisfied with the next: I got the same car as I reserved and they refound on my credit card money for fuel I did not use (It is not so important for EV but say about their customer care). if you use EV on Canary islands share you please experiences with us, surely this topic is very interesting

Answer (score 1):

Canaries are a piece of African exotica with the safety and services of the EU, so definitely go for it. I would choose Tenerife but that's personal preference.

For car rental, all of the companies are relatively decent, but I like Cicar's simple process, automatic excess insurance and second driver, etc.

We just rented an EV here (Tenerife South airport, 2 days ago) and it climbs the insane 30% inclines like a silent space shuttle, but the process of charging it is proving to be something of a nuisance. The charging stations website canariasterecarga.com is terrible and even worse for non-Spanish speakers. But I believe we will score our first charge tomorrow or the day after that. :)